# how is python recursion depth calculated?

Tags: python, recursion

this is my function Foo:

```
def Foo(n=10):
    if 1<n<=10:
        for i in range(1, 10):
            #### Do_Something
            Foo(n-1)
```

I get `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`, which is frustrating since I was expecting Foo's recursion depth to be 10+, nowhere near python's default 500 limits.
I know I'll be getting gigantic amount of stacks with this Foo, but that is bearable. I tried increasing `sys.setrecursionlimit` and still getting RuntimeError. Any suggestions?

Comment: Cannot reproduce -- I have it executing just fine. The stack depth maxes out at 10.

Comment: What makes you think the maximum depth is 10-ish?

Comment: @kindall because Foo(n) only calls Foo(n-1) if n <= 10.

Comment: Maybe in your original code you call `Foo(i-1)` instead of `Foo(n-1)`?

Comment: Static analysis shows that the max depth is 10. However, in order to ward against brain problems, I added a counter at the function start and end that keeps track of the depth. It stops at 10. http://ideone.com/IQRMlG

Comment: @MagnusHoff -- it looks like we had the same thoughts on that...

Comment: Err, are you sure the code you copied is correct? It ends up calling `Foo` about 1billion times (because of the `for` loop), but the stack is never more than 10 calls deep..

Comment: Neither do I know why it hit maxrecursion : I just truncated every function irrelevant to Foo() and I'm not getting any error. Foo() did not call/depended on other functions but I think there was something that went bad with parsing.. maximum depth is 10, as I presumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit) of `sys.setrecursionlimit` specifies that the recursion limit is actually the *depth of the python stack*.

**EDIT** I don't know why you're hitting the recursion limit, but you're probably not hitting because of this function (I've modified it so that it prints the maximum times it is on the stack):

```
count = 0
maxcount = 0

def Foo(n=10):
    global count
    global maxcount
    count = count + 1

    if(count > maxcount):
        maxcount = count
        print maxcount

    if 1<n<=10:
        for i in range(1, 10):
            #### Do_Something
            Foo(n-1)
    count = count - 1

Foo(10)
```

Comment: But `factorial(10)` is only the case if the calls would happen "intermixed". IMHO the maximum depth is around 10 (which is the case if I try...)

Comment: @glglgl -- You're right.  This shouldn't be hitting the recursion limit (as far as I can see).

Answer (score -1):

There was an error in my calculation apologies. The function does not in fact crash on foo(10) but simply makes 4 billion calls but halts correctly.

Comment: on the first loop iteration where n=10 , the loop will make the following calls : `Foo(9); Foo(9); Foo(9); Foo(9); Foo(9); Foo(9); Foo(9); Foo(9); Foo(9); Foo(9); `

Comment: yes you are right but this makes it even worse

Comment: I have been running foo(10) for about 10 minutes and we are on 130000 calls and it sis still going